# Selenium - Webelement selection

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing automation using Selenium.The site that I am automating has the following html elements. From Selenium I want the grab the "0400320908" and "0400 962887".

I tried below code:-

```
WebElement mobElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(text(),mobile)]"));
```

but the webdriver is grabbing only the first number i.e. 0400320908 but not the other number. Could you please advise what mistake I am doing.

Regards,
Badari

```
<ul class="no-margin no-padding">
<li class="mobile-row landing-module-row">
<a class="with-two-usage" href="plan-details-mobile?accountId=2743a04d777524d37b55e1423264b4b9b6b88455&serviceId=6a7ec405ff27c9712d06ef978a828a6b5300ad70">
<span class="service-title">Mobile</span>
<i class="service-identifier">0400 320 908</i>
</a>
<div class="r-side">
</li>


<script src="/myaccount/static-content/js/unica-domain.js?cb=1.1602.0.1-SNAPSHOT.4.5.8" type="text/javascript">
<li class="mobile-row landing-module-row">
<a class="with-two-usage" href="plan-details-mobile?accountId=2743a04d777524d37b55e1423264b4b9b6b88455&serviceId=25fd1d9b2ae9b04de2a2ccd63e407d957bede4c9">
<span class="service-title">Mobile</span>
<i class="service-identifier">0400 962 887</i>
</a>
<div class="r-side">
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `findElements` to locate multiple elements. I would also use a *CSS selector* in this case as it is more concise and readable:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("i.service-identifier"));
```

If, you need to use the `Mobile` text to locate elements, use the following XPath expression:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class = 'service-title' and . = 'Mobile']/following-sibling::i"));
```